# Azure AD B2C change tenant name

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I see in the [documentation for the *.b2clogin.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) that Azure uses the tenant name as the subdomain. I would like to test this feature, but I also would not like to use my existing tenant name as the subdomain.

Is it possible to change the value used in the *.b2clogin.com pattern itself, or to change my existing B2C tenant name?

Failing both of those, is there a way to transfer my existing tenant configuration over to a new tenant with the name I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see in the documentation for the *.b2clogin.com that Azure uses the
>   tenant name as the subdomain. I would like to test this feature, but I
>   also would not like to use my existing tenant name as the subdomain.

The documentation means you could use your `<YourTenantName>.b2clogin.com`instead of `login.microsoftonline.com`, and this is up to you, you could use one of them. But `<YourTenantName>.b2clogin.com` is not as the subdomain.

> Is it possible to change the value used in the *.b2clogin.com pattern
>   itself, or to change my existing B2C tenant name?

You could not change the name. If you want new, you could try to [create a B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) and then manually configure this.